# https tooltip using the hyperref package

Tags: hyperref

How do I get a https tooltip for a URL without specifying it in the displayed text?

The following shows the right tooltip, but  display `https://` in the text:

```
\url{https://www.google.com/imghp}
```

These display the right text, but show `http://` in the tooltip and also translate to a `http://` scheme URL:

```
\url{www.google.com/imghp}
\href{https://www.google.com/imghp}{www.google.com/imghp}
```

The behavior of the last example above was a bit surprising -- it ignores the https specified in the URL parameter.

Image of the above examples:

[image: image of URL depictions]

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: Tried both Skim and Preview on a Mac.

Comment: the \href variant is correct, and if the pdf viewer really doesn't show the "s" it is a problem/a bug in the viewer, hyperref doesn't remove it.